# Unable to consistently get results, the text in the chrome dev tools changes, The dropdown slector is unable to work

Tags: html, node.js, puppeteer

Basically, for some reason every time I run the code it yields different results. Sometimes it works (except for the select dropdown), sometimes it does work at all. The text in the dev tool changes back and forth so I wanted to know if there was a possibility of looping.Any ideas?Here is the code below

```
async function fillBilling(page){
    
    //await page.waitFor(100);
    //await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(3000);
    await page.waitFor(100);
    await page.waitForSelector('#consolidatedAddresses.ui_address_2.firstName');
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(2000);
    await page.type('#consolidatedAddresses.ui_address_2.firstName', 'John');
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(2000);
    //await page.waitFor(100);
    await page.type("input[id='consolidatedAddresses.ui_address_2.lastName']", 'Doe');
    await page.waitFor(100);
    await page.type("input[id='consolidatedAddresses.ui_address_1270.street']", '97 N Armistead St');
    await page.waitFor(100);
    await page.type("input[id='consolidatedAddresses.ui_address_2.street']", 'Alexandria');
    //await page.waitFor(2000);
    await page.waitForSelector('#consolidatedAddresses.ui_address_2.state', 'VA');
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(2000);
   // await page.waitFor(100);
    //await page.click("input[id='consolidatedAddresses.ui_address_2.state']");
    //await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(2000);
  //  await page.waitFor(100);
    await page.select('#consolidatedAddresses.ui_address_2.state', 'VA');
```

Comment: please add the code from the image into the post as text like so `test code` https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to SO! Every page is different, so it's almost impossible to help without a [mcve] of the page's HTML/JS or a link to the site you're scraping. I can say for sure that `await page.waitFor(100);` is a race condition, so it's no surprise that it doesn't work. `waitForFunction` or `waitForSelector` is much more robust. Use `waitForTimeout` as a last resort. `await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(2000);` is a strange call to be putting randomly throughout your code. This is a one-time, up-front operation; although this isn't the problem, it's code smell.

Comment: Understood thank you. The thing is that when I use waitForSelector it needs to exceed the 30000ms for some reason.it all depends on what page or section I am on the website though because it most works up until I get the the payment sections.